# Generating PDF`s in MVC3 with Telerik in UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I know this is a duplicate Question. But I didnt get a correct solution to my problem.

**ISSUE :**

I am using MVC3 Razor View Engine and in the UI , we are using Telerik controls.The problem is 
I am displaying the data in the Telerik Grid .Now I have to generate PDF with the same data.
I found couple of solutions ,
 **1) Exporting Data from Telerik MVC grid **(Not shown here)**

```
  @(Html.Telerik()
.Grid(Model.InventoryRecords)
.Name("SiteInventory")
.PrefixUrlParameters(false)
.DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("_AjaxLoading", "InventoryDetails"))
.Columns(columns=>
             {
                 columns.Bound(c => c.ShipmentID).Title("Shipment Number").Width(30);
                 columns.Bound(c => c.PackageStatus).Width(30);
                 columns.Bound(c => c.PackageID).Title("Package Number").Width(30);                    
                 columns.Bound(c => c.ConfirmationDate).Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}").Title("Confirmation Date").Width(40);

             }) 
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
.TableHtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
.Filterable()
.Sortable()
.Pageable(paging=>paging.PageSize(15).Style(GridPagerStyles.NextPreviousAndNumeric))

)
```

**2) other option is using itextSharp to generate PDF**

Now I am confused which option to choose first of all to start, which one is better.

I didn`t find right articles to start either of them.

Can you guys guide me suggest right articles for either of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example of using iTextSharp to export a Telerik MVC Grid to PDF available [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/export-to-pdf.aspx). I have used iTextSharp many times in the past, and highly recommend it :)!

Hope this helps!